# How do I share remaining SSD space among Ubuntu partitions while dual booting Windows 10(pre-installed) and Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-10

Due to some crashes I had on Ubuntu, I decided to reinstall the OS.

I have a laptop with 500 GB SSD and 16 GB of RAM. It already has Windows 10 installed on it. 300 GB of the total disk space(500 GB SSD) of laptop is occupied by two partitions (one of 120GB - Windows partition, the other of 180GB).
I want to dual boot it with Ubuntu. I'll be using Ubuntu to compile Android Custom ROMs and one source file is ~30GB.

Any ideas on how should I share the rest of the 200GB between the Ubuntu partitions?

I use to use the default scheme for this. I'm using W10 for video editing and need a bit of space (avisynth uses .avi format which takes a lot of space) and I tried to separate the whole SSD for both of the OS. I used to have a 1GB HDD before, but it broke. So I bought the next big thing I could with the money I had, which is the Samsung SSD 500GB. Until now I had 20GB on root. 24GB on swap and the rest were on home.

Comment: So... out of the total 500GB, you want 200GB assigned to Ubuntu and 300GB to Windows 10? I'm not quite sure what you want to accomplish. Please specify what partitions you have and how much you want to assign each.

Comment: IMO this question will give nothing but opinion as you don't give enough detail. My opinion, keep it simple, of the 200GB, 16GB as swap (same as ram for suspend mode) and the rest for Ubuntu. Also this way you should not run out of space in /boot etc...

Comment: I use to use the default scheme for this. I'm using W10 for video editing and need a bit of space (avisynth uses .avi format which takes a lot of space) and I tried to separate the whole SSD for both of the OS. I used to have a 1GB HDD before, but it broke. So I bought the next big thing I could with the money I had, which is the Samsung SSD 500GB. Until now I had 20GB on root. 24GB on swap and the rest were on home.

Comment: Please edit extra information in to your question.

Comment: A 1GB HDD? How did you fit the Ubuntu ISO on that thing?